# Is this a pepper? A weed? An edible weed?

Tags: peppers

I have two similar plants that popped up in my vegetable garden in north Florida. At first I thought they were pepper plants, but now I'm having doubts. I did plant pepper seeds that I took out of store-bought peppers in this area back in the fall. As sometimes happens, nothing came up, so I overseeded the area with beets. Spring rolled around and these plants sprouted. Who can help me identify them?

They both stand about 2' tall, and have very small white flowers with yellow centers. The flowers are held somewhat downward. The fruits done seem to be growing much at all. They're very small, green, and round, and are in clusters of 3-5.

The only differences I see in the plants is that one is multi-stemmed, while the other is basically one stalk. The other thing is that the single-stalk plant has *some* leaves that are serrated.

I'm trying to upload pics, but having trouble...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How can we help with the pictures? Having them would really help...

Comment: Welcome Brian Boe! To add pictures: Press the grey "edit" button at the bottom of your question (or this [edit]). It will open up. Along the top there are icons. One looks like a picture of a mountain. It's next to the brackets. Click on that and a box will come up offering you options to add pictures either from your computer or a website. You can add two. Once you have 10 rep you can post as many as you want. Please let us know if you keep having trouble. We're here to help!

Comment: The serrated-leaf single-stem plant is most definitely not a pepper. So if they look the same otherwise, I'd say you've got two weeds.